# group by keys where keys are dynamic

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to group by key name

```
let data =  [ 
  { '0': '09/23/2019' },
  { '0': '23' },
  { '1': '09/10/2019' },
  { '1': '34' },
  { '2': '09/17/2019' },
  { '2': '45' } ]
```

Desired output

```
data = [
{ date: 09/23/2019,
  number: 23
},
{ date: 09/10/2019,
  number: 34
}]
```

I have tried to use `_.groupBy` however it only accepts two arguments collection and value.

I have also tried using `mapKeys`, but I didn't get the expected output.

```
let test = _.mapKeys(arrayData, function(value, key) {
  return {
    date: value[key],
    number:  value[key]
  };
});

console.log(test)
```

here is my [repl](https://repl.it/@DeanKamali/ProudResponsibleTelevisions)

Comment: Where do `date` and `number` (as strings) come from in your code?

Comment: @JackBashford good point, I will convert dates `09/23/2019` to date object, and I will try to sort them via `isDate` method probably.

Comment: Are the objects always ordered like this, with related date and number sequential?

Comment: The data in your REPL is in a different form than what you show here. I assume you are parsing the REPL data to match the list shown in your question, is that correct? Perhaps you just need to back up a step and parse the data directly into the structure that you want rather than parsing it into a structure that you then have to rearrange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at your repl, it looks like you really want to transform the following object:

```js
const data = {
  'true[0][the_date]': "09/23/2019",
  'true[0][toothNumber]': "23",
  'true[1][the_date]': "09/10/2019",
  'true[1][toothNumber]': "34",
  'true[2][the_date]': "09/17/2019",
  'true[2][toothNumber]': "45",
};
```

into this:

```js
[
  { date: '09/23/2019', number: '23' },
  { date: '09/10/2019', number: '34' },
  { date: '09/17/2019', number: '45' }
]
```

and if that's the case, you can simply use a for loop:

```js
const group = [];
for (let keys = Object.keys(data), i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 2)
  group.push({
    date: data[keys[i]],
    number: data[keys[i + 1]],
  });
```

that's it, you don't need any special utility for those kind of objects that are usually generated from DBs or similar services, plus you drop a dependency, and you go faster than any utility.

Would this work as well? Or you really need to use lodash for this?

Answer (score 3):

You could specify an array of keys which are used in the given order and take an object for keeping track of the index for the key.

```js
var data =  [{ 0: '09/23/2019' }, { 0: '23' }, { 1: '09/10/2019' }, { 1: '34' }, { 2: '09/17/2019' }, { 2: '45' }],
    keys = ['date', 'number'],
    indices = {},
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var [k, v] = Object.entries(o)[0];
        indices[k] = indices[k] || 0;
        r[k] = r[k] || {};
        r[k][keys[indices[k]++]] = v;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary with the key in each item as an index and identify the number and date with simple `isNaN(+value)` - which returns `NaN` for date and a valid number for type number.

I used `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.values` to solve it

```js
let data =  [ 
  { '0': '09/23/2019' },
  { '0': '23' },
  { '1': '09/10/2019' },
  { '1': '34' },
  { '2': '09/17/2019' },
  { '2': '45' } ];
  
const output = Object.values(data.reduce((out, val) => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(val).pop();

  out[key] = out[key] || {};
  // this does the magic
  out[key][isNaN(+value) ? 'date' : 'number'] = value;

  return out;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console { height: 100%;}
```